# Creating Element UI tooltip content that changes depending on the table-row

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I have a method that returns a string to the tooltip content based on the column's value in an Element UI table, however it is only returning the first column's value instead of changing once hovered over.

```
<el-table-column label="Service Lines / MSDRG" prop="code" sortable min-width="120">
  <template slot-scope="slotData">
    <el-tooltip 
      effect="dark" 
      placement="top-start" 
      :content="returnSvclinesValue(slotData.row.code , name)"
    >
    <span>{{ slotData.row.code }}</span>
    </el-tooltip>
   </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Here is the method for `returnSvclineValue(code, name)`

```
returnSvclinesValue: function(code, name) {
  const svclinesTrimmedByName = svclines.find(i => i.label == name && i.value == name)
  const svclineValue = svclinesTrimmedByName.children.find(l => l.value = code )
  return svclineValue.label
}
```

For the method `returnSvclinesValue(code, name)`, it works, I just need it to render a different content based on the row's code..is there some type of work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a computed property with parameters as mentioned below:

```
computed:{
   returnSvclinesValue(){
      return (code, name)=> {
       const svclinesTrimmedByName = svclines.find(i => i.label == name && i.value == name)
       const svclineValue = svclinesTrimmedByName.children.find(l => l.value == code )
       return svclineValue.label
     }
  }

}
```